# Using && for character vectors in r

Tags: r, boolean

The && boolean operator seems to work differently with character vectors and I was wondering if anyone knows why.

For example:

```
streetA <- c("green", "green", "red")

streetB <- c("green", "green", "green")
```

`streetA == "green" && streetB == "green"`

returns TRUE, but the statement should return FALSE since streetA has a "red" in it.

The & statement works as expected:

`streetA == "green" & streetB == "green"`

returns: TRUE  TRUE FALSE

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: "The && boolean operator seems to work differently with character vectors" : different compared to what? That's expected behavior.

Comment: [Logical AND](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html) "evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector". Try changing the first "green" in one of the vectors to "blue"; you'll get FALSE.

Comment: Different compared to integer values.  It's an and operator so it should on return TRUE if all are true.  OR || returns TRUE if one side is TRUE

Comment: Nope. Integer vectors work the same way with these operators.

Comment: Yup, you're right. For some reason, I thought the operator did a pairwise comparison and broke once it got its first FALSE.

Comment: You might be interested in `all()` and `any()`. Seems like you're aiming for `all(streetA == "green") && all(streetB == "green")`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Gregor! That is what I was looking for.  Thank you, everyone, for your help and input on this.

Answer (score 5):

From the `&&` documentation:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.